# Authentication with HTTPOnly Cookie with Angular 5 and Ionic 3

Tags: angular, authentication, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, httponly

I am working on a mobile application which is having Angular 5 and Ionic 3 Stack. The backend is using session authentication with the help of a cookie. The problem is that the session cookie is set:

> HTTPOnly = True

Meaning Javascript cannot read it. Now I think due to this, I am not able to do to my authentication as my JS code cannot store and send that cookie with next request. Also, due to some reasons, it is not possible to set HTTPOnly false.

Is there a way I can get past this and do the authentication.

### P.S:

I tried with Angular 6 and Ionic 4 with some proxy setup(in angular.json) like this and able to do bypass this, but I don't think this is a good idea to use beta versions yet:

```
"proxies": [
{
"path": "/api",
"proxyUrl": "http://dev.mysite.com/api"
}
]
```

Comment: Cookie: .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=<tokens>; path=/; secure; HttpOnly